# Delete s3 bucket object

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm facing problems when deleting objects from an S3 bucket, my policies are these:

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::frienlinkfotos/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::frienlinkfotos"
        }
    ]
}
```

My permissions allow me to see and delete objects, so based on that, I made this function in Golang to delete objects in a bucket:

```html
func DeletePost(c *gin.Context) {
    // iniciando aws
    service := utils.UtilAWS()
    svc := s3.New(service)

    //pegando id_usuario a partir do contexto
    IDUser := utils.GetUserJWT(c)

    uuidPost := c.PostForm("uuid_post")
    IDPost, err := strconv.Atoi(c.PostForm("id_post"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Erro ao converter id", err)
        c.Status(400)
        return
    }

    _, err = DB.Exec(`DELETE FROM post WHERE id_post = ? AND id_usuario_pt = ? AND uuid_post = ?`, IDPost, IDUser, uuidPost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Erro ao deletar post", err)
        c.Status(400)
    } else {
        c.Status(200)
    }

    // deletando tambem do bucket:
    Bucket := os.Getenv("Bucket")
    log.Println(Bucket)
    _, err = svc.DeleteObject(&s3.DeleteObjectInput{Bucket: aws.String(Bucket), Key: aws.String(uuidPost)})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Erro ao deletar post do S3 bucket", err)
        c.JSON(400, err)
    }
    err = svc.WaitUntilObjectNotExists(&s3.HeadObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(Bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(uuidPost),
    })
}
```

but this function gives me this error:

```html
Error when deleting post from S3 bucket AccessDenied: Access Denied
        status code: 403, request id: HMMCQN87, host id: GFtkmaI4hBft5Sh9U78/HIAljTcTYzW29J8hG6JavZxBMjubBvDaf5ia57e9PAd/q5I=
```

Why even releasing permissions for deletion, I cannot delete any object?
Listing my objects is going smoothly.

For more information, my service only has this function:

```html
package utils

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
)

var s3Session = session.New()

func UtilAWS() *session.Session {
    //Variaveis de login para o aws
    region := os.Getenv("REGION")
    key := os.Getenv("KEY")
    secretpass := os.Getenv("SECRETPASS")
    if region == "" || key == "" || secretpass == "" {
        log.Println("informações de login da AWS não pode ser nulas")
    }

    s3Config := &aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String(region),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(key, secretpass, ""),
    }

    s3Session = session.New(s3Config)
    return session.New(s3Config.WithRegion(region))
}
```

Comment: In general, don't use S3 bucket policies to supply permissions to IAM principals (user and roles) that are in the same AWS account. Instead, attach IAM policies to those IAM principals. In your specific case, you've given everyone access and this is a dangerous policy so you should remove the bucket policy asap.

Comment: Your Bucket Policy means that everyone in the world (including me) can now upload objects to your bucket, delete object and list objects (eg I just found `post/2465d4d5-85fd-4f11-b975-92cb59928705`). You should **delete this bucket policy immediately**!

Comment: In my case, the project I'm doing is a portfolio, it's a social network, the images can be seen by anyone who logs into the social network
But I want that when a user deletes a post, the image/video is also deleted from my s3, what would be the most recommended practice? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: This would be the responsibility of your app, since only the app 'understands' what it means to delete a post. The app should keep track of which files are associated with a post and then delete the object when it isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Bucket policy is fine, but lambda(or other aws service) execution role is missing s3 access, for lambda go to

`IAM > roles > find your lambda execution role > permissions > add s3 full access permission`

Remember to block public access if there is valueable data, I could delete the objects from your bucket

Comment: instead of giving full access you(which is not recommended) you should suggest to give specific access rights. i.e. `AllowDeleteObjects`

Comment: In all likelihood, the OP's S3 bucket policy is *not* fine (it allows anyone to get and delete objects, as you indicated). Regardless of Block Public Access (BPA) settings, this is not a good bucket policy.

Comment: In my case, the project I'm doing is a portfolio, it's a social network, the images can be seen by anyone who logs into the social network
But I want that when a user deletes a post, the image/video is also deleted from my s3, what would be the most recommended practice?  @jarmod

Comment: Track the S3 assets associated with a given post so that your back-end application can delete them when it is asked to delete a post. You can do that with key/value lookup in DynamoDB or you could simply structure your S3 assets to always be under a prefix such as `<post-id>/`. But please remove the bucket policy and apply the permissions needed to the IAM role that your back-end service assumes.